# Using lejos for NXT with Linux

Tags: java, linux, nxt, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I have a Mindstorms NXT and only could flash it with sudo right?
So now I want to upload a test program, but:

```
Initializing LeJOS JDK at /opt/lukas/lejos
Linking ...
Program has been linked successfully
Uploading ...
leJOS NXJ> Failed to find any NXTs
leJOS NXJ> Failed to connect to any NXT
No NXT found - is it switched on and plugged in (for USB)?
uploading the program failed with exit status 1
```

I use eclipse an d the eclipse plugin.
The NXT is turned on and also connected via USB, I think there are a few permission problems. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the driver (kernel module) for NXT? Look at `dmesg` output, check what messages appear when you connect the NXT USB.

Comment: [46418.380087] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd
[46418.554116] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0694, idProduct=0002
[46418.554126] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[46418.554134] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 001653037901